# Passing information from database into javascript via rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass a table cell from my database into the javascript code i'm wondering how to do this?

I was wondering if this would work

```
var = (<%= @event.name %>)
```

Also if the javascript is active on the show, Would @event call from the controller method in the same way? so this would work fine still?

```
  def show
    @event = Newevent.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Thanks for input

Sam

Answer (score 0):

In your view you can do:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var eventName = @event.name;
<% end %>
```

Also checkout [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) it embeds Rails variables into your js.